# how to shift column to next row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
   code   date       tank    product    time_frst   time_lst   qty_frst   qty_lst
   123   2019-01-01  1       MS         02:00:00    10:00:00   234        100  
   123   2019-01-01  2       HS         02:30:00    19:00:00   200        50
   123   2019-01-01  3       MS         00:30:00    22:00:00   300        500
```

My desired dataframe is as follows

```
  code    date        tank    product      time        qty
  123     2019-01-01  1       MS           02:00:00    234
  123     2019-01-01  1       MS           10:00:00    100
  123     2019-01-01  2       HS           02:30:00    200
  123     2019-01-01  2       HS           19:00:00    50
  123     2019-01-01  3       MS           00:30:00    300
  123     2019-01-01  3       MS           22:00:00    500
```

How can I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` by all columns without `_`, so possible `split` all another columns to `MultiIndex in columns` and last reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), for remove unnecesary column use first `reset_index` and second is for convert `MultiIndex in index` to columns:

```
df = df.set_index(['code','date','tank','product'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=4, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
   code        date  tank product  qty      time
0   123  2019-01-01     1      MS  234  02:00:00
1   123  2019-01-01     1      MS  100  10:00:00
2   123  2019-01-01     2      HS  200  02:30:00
3   123  2019-01-01     2      HS   50  19:00:00
4   123  2019-01-01     3      MS  300  00:30:00
5   123  2019-01-01     3      MS  500  22:00:00
```